# Use AEM React SPA Components/Xfs in different projects/sites

Tags: reactjs, adobe, single-page-application, aem

I want to use my AEM React SPA components and experience fragments in different projects like we use our HTL projects. How can I achieve it? For normal HTL components in a non-spa project we can easily use our components/experience fragments in different projects.

I tried to make include the React components using polices but it was not showing up on the page. I also tried to add the clientlibs from the first project to the new project but that too didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.